# Installing Ubuntu on an XP laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have two XP computers (A and B) with no CD.  I'd like to convert B to Ubuntu (no XP partition) via a USB that I can write from A. But I don't want to install Ubuntu on A.  Is this possible?  I would also like not to go on-line with B until it is safely Ubuntized, as it's been hacked and probably dangerous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: If a laptop still runs XP, I would recommend a lighter distribution of Ubuntu, such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: @Robby1212 I don't see how the link you provided addresses in any way the interest of the OP here

Comment: He's asking how to create a bootdisk without a CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rufus USB installer. (https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Worked for me and runs on Windows.

*Edit:*
Google helps a lot here:

Step by Step http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-ubuntu-usb-drive-using-rufus/

The iso:

This of course depends totally what System you want to install. For Ubuntu find it on http://ubuntu.com/, lubuntu would be on http://lubuntu.net, xubuntu on http://xubuntu.net, .....

Never had problems with Rufus so far .. make Shure you start Rufus with the USB already connected
There is a known issue with some USB sticks refer here: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/134

Comment: I tried this and it tells me: "0 devices found" even though my USB stick is inserted and recognized by computer A's file system.  Also where on the web can I find the ISO file to point to further down rufus's dialog?  Sorry, I'm really new at this -- is there a step by step somewhere?   Thanks

Comment: see my edit of the answer please